Independence of XORed random variables
Let $s_1 , \cdots , s_l \sim U\{0, 1\}^n$ - independent random variables uniformly distributed over $\{0, 1\}^n, J_1 \subset \{1 , \cdots , l\}, J_2 \subset \{1 , \cdots , l\}$.
Define $r_{J_1} = \bigoplus_{j\in J_1} s_j, r_{J_2} = \bigoplus_{i\in J_2} s_i $.
How do I prove that $r_{J_1}$ and $r_{J_2}$ are independent?
My attempt:
Let $J = J_1 \cap J_2$. Then
$$
\mathbb{P}(r_{J_1} = x \wedge r_{J_2} = y) = 
\mathbb{P}(\bigoplus_{j\in J_1} s_j = x \wedge \bigoplus_{i\in J_2} s_i = y) =
\mathbb{P}(\bigoplus_{j\in J_1 \setminus J} s_j \oplus \bigoplus_{k \in J} s_k = x \wedge \bigoplus_{i\in J_2 \setminus J} s_i \oplus \bigoplus_{l \in J} s_l = y) = 
\sum_{\bigoplus_{k \in J} s_k = z} \mathbb{P}(\bigoplus_{j\in J_1 \setminus J} s_j \oplus z = x \wedge \bigoplus_{i\in J_2 \setminus J} s_i \oplus z = y) = 
\sum_{\bigoplus_{k \in J} s_k = z} \mathbb{P}(\bigoplus_{j\in J_1 \setminus J} s_j = x \oplus z) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\bigoplus_{i\in J_2 \setminus J} s_i = y \oplus z)
$$
But how do I collapse that to get $\mathbb{P}(r_{J_1} = x) \mathbb{P}(r_{J_2} = y)$?

After some research, I came up the following proof.
$$
\mathbb{P}(r_{J_1} = x \wedge r_{J_2} = y) = \mathbb{P}(r_{J_1} = x | r_{J_2} = y)\mathbb{P}(r_{J_2} = y) \\
\mathbb{P}(r_{J_1} = x | r_{J_2} = y) = \mathbb{P}(\bigoplus_{j\in J_1 \setminus J} s_j \oplus \bigoplus_{k \in J} s_k = x \wedge \bigoplus_{i\in J_2 \setminus J} s_i \oplus \bigoplus_{l \in J} s_l = y)
$$
Let $s_{J_1} = \bigoplus_{j\in J_1 \setminus J} s_j, s_{J_2} = \bigoplus_{j\in J_2 \setminus J} s_j, s_{J} = \bigoplus_{j\in J} s_j$.
Note that $s_{J_1}, s_{J_2}, s_{J}$ are iid, uniformly distributed over $\{0, 1\}^n$. Then $\mathbb{P}(r_{J_1} = x | r_{J_2} = y) = \mathbb{P}(s_{J_1} \oplus s_{J} = x | s_{J_2} \oplus s_{J} = y) = \mathbb{P}(s_{J_1} \oplus s_{J_2} = x \oplus y | s_{J_2} \oplus s_{J} = y)$
Since $s_{J_1} \oplus s_{J_2}$ is uniformly distributed over $\{0, 1\}^n$
$$
\mathbb{P}(s_{J_1} \oplus s_{J_2} = x \oplus y | s_{J_2} \oplus s_{J} = y) = \frac{1}{2^n} = \mathbb{P}(s_{J_1} \oplus s_{J} = x) = \mathbb{P}(r_{J_1} = x)
$$

(1) Getting Independence necessitates that $J_1 \not = J_2$ , otherwise , we will get dependence trivially.
The Claim must cover that. The Proof must handle that.
(2) We can show that Claim using simpler intuitive ways : Consider just $s_1 , s_2 , s_1\text{ XOR }s_2$ , rather than all $l$ variables at one shot.
When that is done , all other Combinations & Permutations will follow Naturally & Inductively.
(3) Showing Independence of $s_1 , s_1\text{ XOR }s_2$ is easy , standard , well-known.
(4) We might alternately involve Independence of $s_1\text{ XOR }s_2 , s_2\text{ XOR }s_3$ , which collapses all the common variables into $s_2$ , while $s_1,s_3$ are the non-common collapsed variables.

However, there is a proof in Goldreich's "Foundations of Cryptography, Vol. 1", p. 68-69, but I can't clearly understand it. It looks like this:
Let $j \in J_1, k \in J_2 \setminus J_1$ for $J_1 \neq J_2$. Then $\mathbb{P}[r_{J_2} = \beta | r_{J_1} = \alpha] = $ (why?) $ = \mathbb{P}[s_k = \beta | s_j = \alpha] = \mathbb{P}[s_k = \beta] =$ (why?) $ = \mathbb{P}[r_{J_2} = \beta]$
